# Convert jmeter test into selenium

Tags: java, selenium, jmeter, jmx

I have a Jmeter test file (JMX) and want to convert this file into selenium test, and have no idea how to do. Can anybody suggest something?

Comment: It is not real. Are you going to translate server calls into interaction with UI?

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose of this operation ? 
jMeter (jmx) script should  be considered as a set of HTTP requests (client request<-> server response) . 
And selenium test - is a sequence of user actions  on web UI of application. 
It is impossible as you are trying to convert "crocodiles" into "yellow"  .

What alterntive I would recommend you - try  to  use
[WebDriver Sampler  in jMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) :

To use Selenium Webdriver with JMeter, simply install "Webdriver Set" plugins. The WebDriver sampler is super useful if you want to test for performance AJAX, GWT based web applications and simulated user actions.

Download WebDriver plugins:
cd $JMETER_HOME
wget http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/file/JMeterPlugins-WebDriver-1.1.1.zip

Unzip archive:
unzip JMeterPlugins-WebDriver-1.1.1.zip

Unzipped files must be located in the lib/ folder. To test if WebDriver plugins installed open Jmeter and test if there is jp@gc - Firefox Driver Config.
*If not, be sure to check your JMeter's lib folder.

[image: adding webDriver sampler]

Write your WebDriver script as usual, then add "Thread Group" to your "Test Plan".
Add "Config Element" -> "HTTP Cookie Manager", "Config Element" -> "jp@gc - Firefox Driver Config", "Sampler" -> "jp@gc - Web Driver Sampler", "Listener" -> "View Results Tree".
Bake  for 20 minutes on 350 degrees and it will come out looking like this: 
 [image: webdriver sampler]

You do not need configure two config elements, just skip 'em. Open the "Web Driver Sampler" and add this code:

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait)
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000)

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://duckduckgo.com')
var searchField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('search_form_input_homepage'))
searchField.click()
searchField.sendKeys(['blazemeter'])
var button = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('search_button_homepage'))
button.click()
var link = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.ByCssSelector('#r1-0 > div.links_main > h2 > a.large > b'))
link.click()
WDS.log.info(WDS.name + ' has logged an entry');
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

(Don't worry if you haven't yet grasped the entire code. We'll revisit it a few paras down.)

Now try to start your test. And whatever you do, DO NOT change the "Thread Group" values, they must all be 1!

[image: thread group setUp]

Comment: thanks, but I want to convert my existing JMX test into webdriver, or Selenium?